# Jupyterlab opens default environment

Tags: python, manjaro, jupyter

Recently it happened that my `jupyter lab` does not open the environment that it is started in, but the default environment.

It could be that this issue comes from an update of my OS (Manjaro) I did recently. But I have no clue how to fix this.

I have no idea what I should do now.. :\

This is my OS btw:

```
Host: tillmann-pc Kernel: 4.19.56-1-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: i3 4.16.1 
           Distro: Manjaro Linux 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Apple product: MacBookPro10,2 v: 1.0 serial: <root required> 
           Mobo: Apple model: Mac-AFD8A9D944EA4843 v: MacBookPro10,2 serial: <root required> 
           UEFI: Apple v: 274.0.0.0.0 date: 09/17/2018 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 66.6 Wh condition: 66.9/73.9 Wh (90%) 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i5-3210M bits: 64 type: MT MCP L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
           Speed: 1197 MHz min/max: 1200/3100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1197 2: 1197 3: 1197 4: 1197 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.5 driver: intel resolution: 2560x1600~60Hz, 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Ivybridge Mobile v: 4.2 Mesa 19.1.1 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel 7 Series/C216 Family High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.19.56-1-MANJARO 
Network:   Device-1: Broadcom and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57786 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe driver: N/A 
           Device-2: Broadcom and subsidiaries BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n driver: bcma-pci-bridge 
           Device-3: Realtek RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter type: USB driver: r8152 
           IF: enp0s20u1u4 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 00:e0:4c:68:00:35 
           IF-ID-1: wlp3s0b1 state: up mac: 20:c9:d0:7b:39:41 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 113.00 GiB used: 60.77 GiB (53.8%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Apple model: SSD SM128E size: 113.00 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 93.87 GiB used: 60.77 GiB (64.7%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2 
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 16.83 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda3 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 72.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 198 Uptime: 21m Memory: 7.67 GiB used: 2.64 GiB (34.4%) Shell: zsh
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed it, never mind:
It turned out that there additionally to the jupyter package a jupyterlab package, that I had only installed in my main python version. After installing jupyterlab for the environment version, I could use it.

Reference: 
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/since-last-update-cant-open-jupyter-inside-of-python-environment/94055/6

Someone remind me if I forget to put this as solved in 2 days